# Error creating PDFs at ExportAsFixedFormat: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio-2017, garbage-collection

Error message:  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC'

Hello,
In my VB.Net app, I think there is a problem with how Excel gets released/closed at the end of the two Excel processes. 
I thought that because the program runs fine and saves the Excel files as PDF, but every time it never creates all the files: it stops randomly after a number of PDF files get created at the line where there is "ExportAsFixedFormat". It never stops at the same specific file, so I would say there isn't a problem with any specific PDF.
I have been trying to solve this forever and looked at an endless number of forums but still no success. Pretty please help.  Thank you very much

**THIS IS THE LINE IT ERRORS OUT:**

```
xwb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, "\\ken-resourcesan\fileshares\fieldshare\IT\nsantagata\ARStatements_CustomerInvoicesPDF\" & originalCustomerName & " " & customerNumber & " " & todaysDate & ".pdf")
```

**THIS CREATES THE EXCEL DOCUMENT AND FILLS IT WITH DATA:**

```
Public Sub PopulateSheet(ByVal dt As Data.DataTable, ByVal File As String)
        Dim oXL As Excel.Application = CType(CreateObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
        Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
        Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim oRng As Excel.Range
        oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add
        oSheet = CType(oWB.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet)

'******Spreadsheet gets populated
......

'******Then
oWB.SaveAs(File)

System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oRng)
oRng = Nothing
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oSheet)
oSheet = Nothing
oWB.Close()
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWB)
oWB = Nothing
oXL.Quit()
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oXL)
oXL = Nothing
GC.Collect()
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
GC.Collect()
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

**THIS SAVES THE DOCUMENT AS PDF:**

```
Dim xl As Object
Dim xwb As Object
xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

dt = CreateTable()

PopulateSheet(dt, "\\ken-resourcesan\fileshares\fieldshare\IT\nsantagata\ARStatements_CustomerInvoicesExcel\" & originalCustomerName & " " & customerNumber & " " & todaysDate & ".xlsx")

'Open xlsx doc to save as pdf
xwb = xl.Workbooks.Open("\\ken-resourcesan\fileshares\fieldshare\IT\nsantagata\ARStatements_CustomerInvoicesExcel\" & originalCustomerName & " " & customerNumber & " " & todaysDate & ".xlsx")

xwb.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Zoom = False
xwb.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
xwb.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = False

'Save as pdf
xwb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, "\\ken-resourcesan\fileshares\fieldshare\IT\nsantagata\ARStatements_CustomerInvoicesPDF\" & originalCustomerName & " " & customerNumber & " " & todaysDate & ".pdf")

Dt.Dispose()

xwb.Close()
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xwb)
xwb = Nothing
xl.Quit()
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xl)
xl = Nothing
GC.Collect()
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
GC.Collect()
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: Random errors like this are never easy to help with.  Likely cause is environmental.  And by that it's probably something in the OS that is causing the problem.  Maybe you've hit some file locking issue?

Comment: Hi, if it is like you are saying why would I be able to save say 50 PDF files before it stops?  Plus it never errors out to the same file.